# Could you help me with a script (made on Powershell) to delete files (eventualy subfolders) of a specific folder that are older than 5 days?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

As I said in the question, I have tried to create a script that would delete files and subfolders of a folder that are older than 5 days.

I am new to Powershell, I have already seen some tutorials and read about the syntax of it, but that has not helped me much, so I just found a code that is alike the one I need and I have tried to adapt it to my needs. I will paste it here:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-5)
$path = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\example"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and 
$_.CreationTime -lt $limit} | Remove-Item
```

The script has runned, without any error message, but the files have not been deleted. I would like to know what may be the problem. By the way, would this script delete subfolders as well? Other thing, how do I do to schedule this script?

Note: As I said, I am a beginner, so if someone could clarify these objects for me, I would be very glad: "PSIsContainer", "CreationTime", "|". I have already search what this "$_." means, but I have not understood it well yet, so if someone could tell me it directly, I would be very thankful as well. Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you limited to psv2? the newer version [5.1] is both faster and somewhat easier to use.

Comment: I will try some update then. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: PSv3+ [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-3.0) has the `-File`/`-Directory` properties to select files/directorys. Also PSv3+ `Remove-Item` has the -Force and -Recurse properties you may need. `$_` or `$PSItem` (PSv3+) represent the currently processed pipeline element.

Comment: you are welcome! [*grin*] as for your code - when i run it on my system, it deletes any subfolder that is more than 5 days old. i had to add `-Recurse` to the `Remove-Item` line to avoid the many "do you really want to delete this?" questions, but the code itself works as expected. the only reason you would not see any thing would be if you had no directories that were old enuf to trigger the `Remove-Item` line.

Comment: Perhaps also you would need the [LastWriteTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime?view=netframework-4.8) property instead of the [CreationTIme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime?view=netframework-4.8) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried a different code structure, but that basically does the same thing, and it has worked:

```
$Now=Get-Date

Get-Childitem C:\Users\Me\Downloads | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime –lt 
$Now.AddDays(-5) } | Remove-Item
```

Now I am just not sure if it will delete subfolders as well, and I still need to schedule it, but I will keep on trying it and if I get it, I will bring some update about it here.